# If a substring matches in a string then perform arithmetic operations

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a Dataframe **Test** with 2 columns: Currency & Salary:

```
Currency              Salary
SGD: 2.1  lacs (PA)   2.1   
THB: 3.55 lacs (PA)   3.55  
QAR: 3.12 lacs (PA)   3.12
```

I want to create a column **Salary_in_INR**   which has salary (in INR) with following output

```
Currency               Salary     Salary_in_INR*
SGD:  2.1 lacs (PA)    2.1        128.87  
THB: 3.55 lacs (PA)    3.55         8.66   
QAR: 3.12 lacs (PA)    3.12         9.98
```

1 SGD = 61.37 INR, 1 THB = 2.44 INR, 1 QAR = 22.43 INR

I tried two codes

**CODE 1**

```
if 'SGD' in Test['Currency'].values ==True:
            Test['Salary_in_INR'] = Test['Salary'] * 61.37
        elif 'THB' in Test['Currency'].values ==True:
            Test['Salary_in_INR'] = Test['Salary'] * 2.44 
        else:
            Test['Salary_in_INR'] = Test['Salary'] * 22.43
```

**CODE 2**

```
if Test['Currency'].str.contains('SGD'):
        Test['Salary_in_INR'] = Test['Salary'] * 61.37
    elif Test['Currency'].str.contains('THB'):
        Test['Salary_in_INR'] = Test['Salary'] * 2.44
    else:
        Test['Salary_in_INR'] = Test['Salary'] * 22.43
```

Either did not produce desired result

Comment: Please don't post the same text in the question twice (or more), and format your tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map of conversion rates, you can do this by hand or automatically but with another function, then split the Currency string at the first ':' and only take the first (index 0) part. Then use this first part in the currency conversion dictionary to get the correct conversion rate -> multiply:

```
currency_conversion = {'SGD': 61.37, 'THB': 2.44, 'QAR': 22.43}
df['currency_conversion'] = df['Currency'].str.split(':', n=1).str[0].map(currency_conversion)
df['Salary_in_INR'] = df['salary'] * df['currency_conversion']
```